# Get input type="text" values by checked checkboxes

Tags: php, post, checkbox

I'm doing a little project and want to get all input type="text" values if the checkbox is checked. How does it work?

```html
<form name="test" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" target="_blank">
<?php
    foreach ($data['items'] as $key => $value) {
         echo "<label class=\"Items\">
            <input type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"checked\" name=\"items[]\" value=\"$value\">
            <input type=\"text\" value=\"$value\">
        </label>";
    }
?>
</form>
```

Ive already tried this, but it only returned my checkbox values not my text values.

```php
if(isset($_POST['items'])) {
     $items = $_POST['items'];
}
```

Comment: the above code is invalid and is likely causing errors due to nested double quotes

Comment: i know thanks, i removed the backslashes to make it legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to pass textbox values to server, you also need to give the textbox a name:

```
<input type="text" name="values[]" value="$value">
```

One way to sync your textboxes with your checkboxes is this small hack:

```
foreach ($data['items'] as $key => $value) {
     echo "<label class='Items'>
        <input type='hidden' name='keys[{$key}]' value='checkbox_isnt_selected'>
        <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='keys[$key]' value='$value'>
        <input type="text" name='values[$key]' value='$value'>
    </label>";
}
```

This way, if the checkbox isn't selected, you get `checkbox_isnt_selected` on your server, otherwise, you get the relevant `$value`. The checkbox will overwrite the hidden input's value when checked.

Comment: and how did i check, if the checkbox is checked when i changed the value in input type text?

Comment: I wrote it as a hack under my answer.

Comment: but when i uncheck a checkbox, the value will still be transmitted with `$items = $_POST['keys']` and when i use `$items = $_POST['values']` the value doesnt change

Comment: yes, you can filter it with the keys which sends `checkbox_isnt_selected`. Otherwise you might not match the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use $_POST['items'] to access all data from your form, do it like so :

```
<form name="test" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" target="_blank">
<?php
    foreach ($data['items'] as $key => $value) {
         echo "<label class='Items'>
            <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='items[$key][]' value='$value'>
            <input type='text' name='items[$key][]' value='$value'>
        </label>";
    }
?>
</form>
```